# How can I get the missing records from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Due to an error in our application, a process which normally inserts data to 2 tables, intermittently only updated one table. I need to identify all records where the record was added to Table_A but not added to Table_B. A simplified example of my schema is:

| Table_A |
| --- |
| Table_A_Id |
| ClientId |
| DateAdded |

| Table_B |
| --- |
| Table_B_Id |
| ClientId |
| Category |
| DateAdded |

Both Table_A and Table_B can have multiple duplicate ClientIds so I need to find records where ClientId was added to Table_A on a specific date but Table_B does not have that ClientId with the matching DateAdded record. Can anyone help with some SQL that could identify these missing records?

Comment: You could use the `EXCEPT` clause. `select col1, col2 from tableA except select col1, col2 from tableB`.

Comment: Would this work? 
SELECT A.ClientId, A.DateAdded
FROM Table_A A LEFT JOIN Table_B B ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID
WHERE A.DateAdded = 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND B.DateAdded = 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND B.ClientID IS NULL

Answer (score 3):

You could use the EXCEPT clause to locate the missing data. This will return rows found in Table_A only.

```
select ClientId, DateAdded
from Table_A
except
select ClientID, DateAdded
from Table_B
```